# Using "Chances are..."

Tags: word-usage

Here's the sentence I'm wrestling with: "Chances are most of your customers are..." Is this correct? Or should it be "Chances are that most of your customers..." or "Chances are, most of your customers are..."?

Comment: You don't need *that*.  The comma makes things clearer but isn't strictly needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence has at least two words elided, as is usual in everyday colloquial speech. For anything more formal they ought to be included.

***[The] chances are [that] most of your customers are...***